# C# Readint a txt file and creating an exact copy of it inside a program

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file

I am having problem with reading from a txt file.
It contains several rows and columns of bits.
For instance:

```
10101001 10101010 10101010 11110101[space]
10101010 00011000 11000000 10200111[space]
00001000 10111111 11001010 10010010[space]
```

I can't manage to properly read it. For instance i want to get [1][2] cell and got (11000000). I need to have the same exact representation of the txt file in the program. Know i can only read a whole text and split using spaces to string[]. Unfortunatelty with this attitude i will lose my structure. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you show the code you have? Please explain where you are stuck.

Comment: tried solution from Kellerman Revo and it is not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To acomplish your goal you need to do two steps:

1. Read the entire file.
2. Transform to appropiate structure.

Thanks to LINQ you can accomplish quickly:

```
var cells = (from l in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt")
                    select l.Split(" ".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

Now you can access the cells like this:

```
var value = cells[1][2];
```

Comment: hi. I Cant get cells[1][2]. I used ur solution and i am getting sth like cells[1][]. Second is empty and whenever i am trying to access it i got System.NullReferenceException

Comment: okey for the case that u gave me it is working. But when i put more columns and rows it is not...

Comment: I edit the answer to include removing empty entries.